# Как обернуть одним тегом a вложенные теги а?

Tags: html

Всем привет, подскажите пожалуйста как обернуть одним тегом a вложенные теги а?

https://codepen.io/usdbuy/pen/yLNLVGX

```
<div class="user-notifications__action-context">

<a href="/news/view/14852/#comment59254">
    текст <a href="/users/3493/">@user1</a>, <a href="/users/3530/">@user2</a> текст1 текст2 текст3 <a href="/users/3512/">@user3</a> текст4...
</a> 
 в записи <a href="/news/view/14852/">"Воздвиженской."</a>
```

как такое возможно сделать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: для чего такое извращение ?

Comment: а как по другому? варианты?

Comment: возможные варианты из того что выше имеется

Comment: Что-то не то ты делаешь. Это бессмысленно

Comment: @MaximLensky чтоб ссылаться на ссылки в ссылке. :) Кроме шуток, это  не работает так. Не понятно что требуется, но чтобы ни требовалось, так делать нельзя.

Comment: @MaximLensky я понимаю, что ты знаешь :) Это больше к автору вопроса. Без внятного объяснения задачи трудно что-то вменяемое посоветовать.

Comment: ситуация не очень согласен, а можно регулярку тогда которая решит проблему?  я на php

Comment: надо убрать теги `a` у вложенных ссылок